# Terraform route53 bulk records

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-route53

We have 2k records in single zone managed through f5 dns. We are moving to route53 and planning to manage using terraform.
Looking at tf resource it needs 4 lines of config code that is almost 8k lines it code to manage .
It may turn out crazy as we add.
Any thoughts how big organizations manage?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We made a major DNS migration recently, and after looking into Terraform as the tool to carry this out (we use Terraform for other purposes as well) we've decided to use a tool called **OctoDNS** instead.

OctoDNS is specifically crafted for managing DNS records in one or multiple managed DNS providers, including Route 53. You can list your records in a YAML file and sync that to your provider. You can also use it to automatically export the records from your old provider and then push them to Route 53.

Here's how DNS records look like in Terraform and OctoDNS:

Terraform

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "first_record" {
  zone_id = "${aws_route53_zone.my_domain.zone_id}"
  name    = "www.example.com"
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = ["1.1.1.1"]
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "second_record" {
  zone_id = "${aws_route53_zone.my_domain.zone_id}"
  name    = "sub.example.com"
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = "600"
  records = ["2.2.2.2"]
}
```

OctoDNS

```
sub:
  ttl: 600
  type: A
  value: 2.2.2.2

www:
  ttl: 300
  type: A
  value: 1.1.1.1
```

Comment: Looks good, how does it tackle the dynamic records? We have instances that come and go (as well as its records), how does sync work?

Comment: @Chucks you need to maintain your .yaml configuration files, and whenever they change run `octodns-sync`. This will compute the diff between your DNS provider and configuration file and apply just the modifications